# Button сложной формы

Tags: java, android, изображения, button

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать кнопки сложной формы, допустим границы этой карты в android

Comment: какая-то странная у вас карта :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создаёте свою кастомную кнопку, например в виде прямоугольника(на самом деле можно всё что угодно в `onDraw` отрисовывать):

```
public class RectButton extends View {

    public RectButton(Context context) {
       super(context);
    }

   public RectButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RectButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);

        canvas.drawRect(100, 200, 150, 250, paint);
    }
}
```

Добавляете её на активность программно или через `xml` файл, и потом вешаете на неё обработчик нажатий:

```
RectButton button = (RectButton) findViewById(R.id.rect_button);

button.setOnTouchListener((view, event)-> {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //some code
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //some code
                break;
    }
});
```