# Cлушатель для графики OnDraw

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-canvas

Как сделать слушатель для графики OnDraw в MainActivity на нажатие?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class RectButton extends View {

public RectButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public RectButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public RectButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);

    canvas.drawRect(100, 100, 600, 600, paint);
  }
}
```

Comment: Что слушать то? Какие события?

Comment: на нажатие, открытие activity

Comment: А что `onClick()` не никак?

Comment: проблема в том что мне нужна сложная фигура, а при давлении его на активити его площадь раст вытягивается на весь экран становясь прямоугольным

Comment: В [прошлом вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/636185/177345) вам дали ответ и вы его приняли. Теперь задаете опять такой же вопрос и зачем вы его приняли, если не поняли, что нужно делать. Там есть слушатель `onTouchListener()` - в нем получаете координаты и определяете входят они в вашу сложную фигуру или нет. От этого строите логику.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class RectButton extends View {

boolean isClicked = false;

Rect rect = new Rect(100, 200, 150, 250);

public RectButton(Context context) {
   super(context);
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    if (isClicked)
    {
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    } else
    {
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    canvas.drawRect(rect , paint);
}

@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        int action = event.getActionMasked();


    if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();
            if ((x > rect.left & x < rectf.right) &&
                (y > rect.top & x < rectf.bottom))
                {
                    isClicked = (isClicked)? false:true;  //нажата кнопка
                    invalidate(); //перерисуем view
                }

        }


    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Вместо `isClicked = (isClicked)? false:true` можно просто `isClicked  = !isClicked `.